# How to distribute C++ application with ImageMagick

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

I created C++ application with ImageMagick lib for Windows.
I installed IM on my machine( with development headers and DLLs ), but I need to somehow distribute it to my clients without installations on the client PC.

Is it possible to just copy DLLs, headers, and *.lib into my project and have a working app without installing IM?

Comment: You need the dlls if you use them, ex the libs you include are just wrappers to dll calls. Use a dependency tool or just try the deployment of your program in a virtual machine

Comment: Build with the static libraries instead of the DLLs.

Comment: @molbdnilo Do you have a guide on how to do this for IM?
I got DLLs from the installed IM folder.